# How do I get the information from a submit form with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml, form-submit

I have a form

```
<form name="loginForm" method="POST">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="" />
    <br />
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="submitButton" />
</form>
```

How do I take the information above after hitting the submit button, and do something with said data? Such as,

```
<script>
    function checkLogin(){
    //some code here
    }
</scipt>
```

I really want to know how to use the SUBMIT button, and not just onClick.

Comment: Well if you just use submit, it goes to the server.  If this isn't what you want, then what is the problem with onClick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the onSubmit event:

HTML:

```
<form name="loginForm" method="POST" onsubmit="checkLogin()">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="" />
    <br />
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="submitButton" />
</form>
```

Script:

```
function checkLogin(){
    //  If you return "false" it will stop the form from being submitted
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could specify an onsubmit function for your form.

```
<form name="loginForm" method="POST" onsubmit="checkLogin()">
```

Then in your function, something like:

```
function checkLogin() {
    var username = document.forms["loginForm"]["username"];
    // validate the form. Return false and the form will not be posted to server.
}
```

Comment: Also the return value of checkLogin determines if the request is sent to the server. Return false to prevent the form from being posted to the server.

Answer (score 1):

You will use $.post in the following way {

```
    $.post(URL_TO_YOUR_SCRIPT, { username: $("#username").val(), 
    password: $("#password).val() },
    function(data) {
             alert(data);
    });
```

to achieve this,  you will have to give ID's to your input boxes like

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
```

Cheers!

Comment: This is an jQuery answer and the OP made no indication of using it.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you will need jQuery.js for using $.post.

Comment: Also to prevent page refresh and redirecting to action page, you can make an click event for your submit button:

$('input[type="submit"]').live('click',function(e) { e.preventDefault();
checkLogin();
 });